# Cassandra DB Connection Issue

Tags: java, jdbc, cassandra

I am unable to connect to Cassandra DB. I have tried with port number 9042 but it is throwing an exception given below

```
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Read a negative frame size (-2097152000)!.
```

Due to that I am using port number 9160 for the same. But it is giving me below exception

```
[main] ERROR org.bigsql.cassandra2.jdbc.CassandraConnection - Impossible to connect to server Server Name : org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
```

Please provide the solution on the same. Please see below code that I am using for connection.

```
URL="jdbc:cassandra://server name:9160/schema";
address =address;
user=Username;
pass=Password;
Class.forName("org.bigsql.cassandra2.jdbc.CassandraDriver");
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL,user,pass);
```

Comment: what cassandra version? which driver (and version) are you using? are you sure those two versions match?

Comment: Hi JChrist, Thank you for response. I am using Cassandra 2.1-2 Driver. I am using cassandra-2.1-2.jdbc41.jar for the same. Instead of using classes for datastax (cassandra-driver-mapping-3.0.2.jar). I am using bisql.cassandra2 driver.

Comment: Have you checked whether there is any firewall stopping your connections?

Comment: The error seems to indicate that either `server name` is not the right hostname, or cassandra is not running on port 9160.

Comment: Hi Mark, I have checked on the server name. Host name or server name is correct. For port number 9042 it is connecting in DataStax. But using java code for 9042 port number it is throwing exception specified above. Is that error is occuring because of jar version conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

The `URL` is not correct you have a problem in this URL :

```
URL="jdbc:cassandra://server name:9160/schema";
```

Here is the syntax you should to follow :

```
jdbc:cassandra://host1[:port1][,host2[:port2],...[,hostN[:portN]]][/[keyspace][?options]]
```

So for example :

```
URL="jdbc:cassandra://10.6.99.99:9160/dbname";
```

So in place of `server name` you should to specify the @IP of your database or the right host.

Second after the port number `9160/schema` you should to specify the name of your database and not the schema.

Take a look at :

- [cassandra jdbc driver](http://www.dbschema.com/cassandra-jdbc-driver.html)
- [cassandra jdbc](http://www1.bigsql.org/cassandra/cassandra_jdbc.jsp)

**EDIT**

> As @Mark Rotteveel mention : ..Or the port is wrong, or the port isn't
>   open on the accessible IP address for that hostname

so make sure that this port is open on the accessible IP address for that host name.

Comment: i mean ip address or the **right host** @MarkRotteveel, ok i will edit it

Comment: To be honest when I read something like `jdbc:cassandra://server name:9160/schema`, I just assume that `server name` is anonymization to protect the guilty ;).

Comment: mmm, this still a case because in the error there are this message **Impossible to connect to server Server Name :** for that i supposed that he don't change it or he set the wrong host, @MarkRotteveel i'm wrong?

Comment: then in this case he don't specify the right host or the right server name:) @MarkRotteveel

Comment: Or the port is wrong, or the port isn't open on the accessible IP address for that hostname, etc, etc, etc.