# Unable to connect Cassandra using jdbc driver

Tags: java, jdbc, cassandra, datastax

Hi I am trying to connect with Cassandra using jdbc driver. I am getting the following exception.

```
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Connection url must specify a host, e.g., jdbc:cassandra://localhost:9170/Keyspace1
    at org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.Utils.parseURL(Utils.java:190)
    at org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDriver.connect(CassandraDriver.java:85)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.sub.cas.CqlJdbcTestBasic.main(CqlJdbcTestBasic.java:14)
```

My cassandra server is running fine and can be accessed from cql shell in windows 10 OS.

This is the java class that I have written.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class CqlJdbcTestBasic {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Connection con = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDriver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:cassandra:/root/root@localhost:9160/hr");

        String query = "SELECT empid, emp_first, emp_last FROM User WHERE empid = 1";

        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery(query);

        while (result.next()) {
            System.out.println(result.getString("empid"));
            System.out.println(result.getString("emp_first"));
            System.out.println(result.getString("emp_last"));
        }

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (con != null) {
            try {
                con.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            con = null;
        }
    }
}
}
```

I have gathered my jars from this url :: https://code.google.com/archive/a/apache-extras.org/p/cassandra-jdbc. Unable to find any possible solution. Please help.

Comment: `Connection url must specify a host, e.g., jdbc:cassandra://localhost:9170/Keyspace1`. Yours is not valid: `jdbc:cassandra:/root/root@localhost:9160/hr`

Comment: You can learn here http://stackoverflow.com/a/41951737/5558072

Answer (score -2):

Please, check if you have two slashes before your user name. According to

```
http://www.dbschema.com/cassandra-jdbc-driver.html
```